# Deleting a registry key

Tags: c#

I am trying to delete a registry key sub tree which happens to be SAPI 5 user profile as shown below. The "nameofprofile" is the data value of the subkey and the subkey name is a CLSID but it comes up with an exception telling me that the subkey does not exist?

```
RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Speech\\RecoProfiles\\Tokens\\", true);
RegKey.DeleteSubKeyTree("NameOfProfile");
```

Comment: You're running as a 32-bit application and trying to delete something from the 64-bit registry.

Comment: No I am running x64 application, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Which line is the error on? It is almost certainly right, have you checked in say `regedit` that it exists? I believe `RecoProfiles` does not always exist. Is "NameOfProfile" just an example, or is that its actual name?

Comment: The error is on the second Line. The profile name definitely exists as I have checked with regedit. The actual profile name is "test" and therefore I have RegKey.DeleteSubKeyTree ("test")

Comment: Check your build settings and make sure you dont have prefer 32bit ticked

Comment: I have debug x64

Comment: Are you sure the key is there? Right click the key and choose 'copy item path' then compare with the strings.

Comment: Trailing backslash in the keyname? `Tokens\\",`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
string keyName = @"Software\Microsoft\Speech\RecoProfiles\Tokens";
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, true))
{
   key.DeleteSubKeyTree("NameOfProfile",false);   
}
```

If you get the error again, you can try to run application in administrator mode.

Comment: I don't get any errors running the code above but it doesn't delete the key even as an administrator

Comment: Can you write an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Do a search of the `string[] GetSubKeyNames()` first and see if the sub key exists.

Try ignoring casing in case that is an issue.

```
var name = @"Software\Microsoft\Speech\RecoProfiles\Tokens";
var regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(name, true);
if (regKey != null) {
    using (regKey) {
        var subKeyName = "CLSID";
        var actual = regKey.GetSubKeyNames()
            .FirstOrDefault(n => string.Equals(n, subKeyName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (actual != null) {
            regKey.DeleteSubKeyTree(actual);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So it tells me the key doesn't exist. I am probably misleading everyone for which I apologise. The name of the key is actually a CLSID and its data value "test"

Comment: @Rachel674 update original question to avoid any misleading information.

Comment: The question it does say that "nameofProfile" is the data value of the subkey but Ihave updatedTo make it clear the name of the key is a CLSID

Answer (score 0):

In the end I worked it out myself and I did this which worked fine. I should have said in the post that I always knew the profile name but I did not know the CLSID. No doubt there is an easier way to do this(No special permissions were required which was preferable if possible):

```
public static void DeleteKey (String profileName)
    {            
        // Folder for SAPI 5 user profile tokens
        String keyLocation = @"Software\Microsoft\Speech\RecoProfiles\Tokens";
        RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyLocation, true);  
        // Get a list of Key names and work out which one is the "test" profile
        String [] subKeyNames = key.GetSubKeyNames();
        // Enumerate through the sub key names to find out which one is the "Test" profile
        for(int i = 0; i < subKeyNames.Length; i++)
        {
            RegistryKey subKey =     
            Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Speech\\RecoProfiles\\Tokens\\" + subKeyNames[i]);                
            if(((String)subKey.GetValue("")).Equals(profileName))
            {                                                    
                key.DeleteSubKeyTree(subKeyNames[i]);
                return;
            }                                
        }                            
    }
```